# Clang -- Retrieving the initialization Value for a ParmVarDecl

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, semantics, visitor-pattern

I have a `ForStmt` for which I'd like to retrieve the loop bound which is returned by `GetBoundFunc()` as following:

```
void testASTVistor (int N) {
  N = 123;
  for (int i = 0; i <= GetBoundFunc(N); i++ ){
    //do Sth;
  }  
}
```

`AST` looks something like this for the `N`:

```
 -FunctionDecl 0x55d60e61cd48 <line:3:1, line:8:1> line:3:6 testASTVistor 'void (int)'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x55d60e61cc88 <col:21, col:25> col:25 used N 'int'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x55d60e61d0e8 <col:28, line:8:1>
  ¦ |-BinaryOperator 0x55d60e61ce28 <line:4:3, col:7> 'int' lvalue '='
  ¦ | |-DeclRefExpr 0x55d60e61cde8 <col:3> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x55d60e61cc88 'N' 'int'
  ¦ | `-IntegerLiteral 0x55d60e61ce08 <col:7> 'int' 123
```

However, my ASTRecurvieVisitor code keeps seg faulting when it should return the initialization value of N:

```
class BinaryVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<BinaryVisitor> {
public:
  bool VisitBinaryOperator(clang::BinaryOperator *BO) {
  
      if (const CallExpr *RHS = dyn_cast<CallExpr>(BO->getRHS()->IgnoreParenImpCasts())) {
        if (const DeclRefExpr *DRE = dyn_cast_or_null<DeclRefExpr>(RHS->getArg(0))) {
          if (const ParmVarDecl *PVD = dyn_cast<ParmVarDecl>(DRE->getDecl())) {       
            if (const IntegerLiteral *Bound = dyn_cast<IntegerLiteral>(PVD->getInit()->ignoreImpCasts())) {

    return false;
            }
          }
        }
};

/// ...
BinaryVisitor visitor;
visitor.TraverseDecl(someDecl);
```

Also tried, `evaluateValue()` and `getEvaluatedValue()` and none seemed to bypass the issue.

Comment: The `N` in this example is the local variable, not the function parameter, so the `dyn_cast<ParmVarDecl>` will return `nullptr`. Also the AST dump doesn't match the code example, and your `RecursiveASTVisitor` code doesn't look like it would compile (note `DRF` versus `DRE`). Can you copy/paste the exact code and testcase you're using?

Comment: My bad @RichardSmith. Updated the question.

Comment: You should put a `return false;` at the end of that function. My guess is the segfault is from an uninitialized return value.